# Deleting/Removing a ParseFile from ParseUser (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to remove a ParseFile from a ParseUser. The ParseFile is a profile picture that was created, and I would like to provide my users will the ability to change there profile picture when convenient to them.

I am looking for a way to delete the old ParseFile associated with the profile picture, and just store a new one.

**I cannot seem to get the .remove("photo"); method to work properly, and am not sure if I am going about this the wrong way. What would be the best method to do something like this?**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
        Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
        if (extras2 != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = extras2.getParcelable("data");
            ivProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bitmapByte = stream.toByteArray();

            final ParseFile profilePicture = new ParseFile(
                    "profilePicture", bitmapByte);
            profilePicture.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) {

                    } else {

                        // check to see if ParseFile exists, if it does
                        // delete it and set new ParseFile
                        currentUser.remove("photo");
                        currentUser.put("photo", profilePicture);
                        currentUser.saveInBackground();
                        updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
    return;
}
```

This line of code stops everything from working properly. If you remove this the ParseFile is removed / updated properly.